# Beat Detection with Arduino

Tags: filters, audio, signal-analysis, frequency

I'm trying to make a ***robot dance*** on several songs using **Arduino**.
I need to understand how to get the rhythm from the songs, something like detecting the ***beats***, calculating the ***bpm***..
I'm not expert but I read that probably I'll have to use some filters, is that right? or I can use a simple mic and opamp? do I have to analayze some frequencies?
I hope someone has some ideas and can explaing me how to do such a thing, thanks!! :)

Comment: To compute the BPM of audio reliably would probably be quite computationally intensive and thus a bit tricky to compute on a microprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Sparkfun's spectrum analyzer shield. It will give seven bands measurements of the sound at the input jack. For BPM approximation you could select the band that suits you best for the music style you will be analyzing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for now I've ordered a Mic and I'll try to do something like [this](http://arduino.isnot.tv/post/12046833573/automatic-beat-detector), do you think it could work?? Otherwise, depending on the results I'll consider your suggestion and try with a spectrum analyzer :)